# Yehoshua- Perek 6. What were Hashem’s instructions

Tags: shofar, joshua--book-of

I’m confused in Perek 6. In pesukim 3-5 Hashem tells Yehoshua to circle Yericho for 6 days with kohanim just carrying the shofar and on the 7th day to (circle 7 times)and blow the shofar etc.

In posuk 13, however, it says that from the second day they were blowing the shofars (it even repeats it which the Malbim says it demonstrate that they were blowing them continuously). Am I misunderstanding posukim 3-5 in that Hashem’s instructions are to only blow on the 7th day?

Shkoach in advance

Answer (score 1):

“Am I misunderstanding posukim 3-5 in that Hashem’s instructions are to only blow on the 7th day?”

Yes you do misunderstand possuk 4. The Malbim, Metzudas Dovid and the Abarbanel all comment on verse 4, that the kohanim blew shofar on all 7 days.

[MALBIM](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.6.4?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en)

> **והכהנים יתקעו**. ר"ל בכל ז' ימים

.